# I want to run commands like make ,make install and python setup install

Tags: python, linux, directory, makefile, setup.py

Actually i have written a script which will download software from internet to the home dir of the current user and the it will untar it .And the i have make and make install it and in some software i have to run python setup.py install But now problem is that i did not want change the current dir to run all those commands.

is there is any way to specify path in commands (make ,make install ,python setup install)

like: python /home/username/Desktop/urllib/setup.py install

make /home/username/Desktop/somedir/

make install /home/username/Desktop/somedir/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page for `make`:

```
-C dir, --directory=dir
     Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything 
     else.  If multiple -C options are specified,  each  is interpreted  
     relative to the previous one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C /etc.  
     This is typically used with recursive invocations of make.
```

So, you ought to be able to type:

```
make -C /home/username/Desktop/somedir/
make -C /home/username/Desktop/somedir/ install
```

There is nothing equivalent in Python command line. But you may consider using this in your shell script:

```
(cd /home/username/Desktop/urllib/ && python setup.py install)
```

The commands in the parentheses are executed in a "subshell". So the working directory of your script will not change but the `python` command will be executed from the `/home/username/Desktop/urllib/` directory. The use of `&&` ensures that the Python command will not be executed unless the `cd` command is successful. You can use the same trick with the `make` command also:

```
(cd /home/username/Desktop/somedir/ && make && make install)
```